# Is $F: H^{1}(\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(v):= \int_{\Omega} | Du|^2 dx$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity

> I'm wondering about the folowing question motiveted by existence of weak solutions to the Dirichlet Problem. The function $F: H^{1}(\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   \begin{equation}
> F(v):= \int_{\Omega} \|Du\|^2 dx
> \end{equation}
>   is continous?

**My idea:**

\begin{eqnarray}
\left | \int_{\Omega} \| Du\|^2 dx - \int_{\Omega} \| Dv\|^2 dx \right | &\le &  \int_{\Omega}  \left | \| Du\|^2  -  \| Dv\|^2 \right | dx  \\
&\le &  \int_{\Omega} \|D(u)-D(v)\|^2dx?\\
&\le &  \int_{\Omega} \|D(u-v)\|^2dx\\
&\le &  \|u-v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}
\end{eqnarray}

How to foud out an inequality like the second one? Maybe nust exist a constant before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $|v|_0=\left(\int_{\Omega}|Dv|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$ has all of the properties of a norm except possibly strict positivity. That's enough to give you the triangle inequality and reverse triangle inequality:
$$
              |\,|v|_0-|u|_0| \le |v-u|_0.
$$
And that's enough to establish the continuity of $G: H^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $G(v)=|v|_0$ because
$$
    |G(u)-G(v)| \le |u-v|_0 \le \|u-v\|_{H^1}.
$$
Your function is $F(v)=G(v)^2$, which is the composition of the square function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $G$. So $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, but how to prove triangle inequality for $|v|_0$?

Comment: @user29999 : The triangle inequality for $|\cdot|_0$ follows from the triangle inequality for the $L^2$ norm. $|v+w|_0 = \|Dv+Dw\|_{L^2}\le \|Dv\|_{L^2}+\|Dw\|_{L^2}=|v|_0+|w|_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (your end result is not correct, e.g. wrong homogeneity). Use instead $$ \| Du \| = \|Dv + Du-Dv\| \leq \|Dv\| + \|Du-Dv\|$$
(and the same with $u$, $v$ interchanged) to arrive at:
 $$ \left| \; \| Du \| -  \|Dv\| \right| \leq \|Du-Dv\|.$$
Whence
$$ \left| \; \| Du \|^2 -  \|Dv\|^2 \right|
 \leq \|D(u-v)\|(\| Du \| +  \|Dv\|) .$$
After a little calculation (using Cauchy-Schwarz for $L^2$ functions):
 $$ |F(u)-F(v)|\leq \int \left| \; \| Du \|^2 -  \|Dv\|^2 \right|\; dx
 \leq \|u-v\|_{H^1} (\|u\|_H^1 + \|v\|_{H^1}) .$$
Thus implying continuity.

Comment: I really appreciated your hint. But in fact, I guess I need more details beucause I followed it and I can't finalize. I Also tried,

Comment: If 
\begin{equation}
\left |\|Du\|^2 -\|Dv\|^2\right | = \|Du\|^2 -\|Dv\|^2,
\end{equation}
then $\|Du\|\ge \|Dv\|$. However
$$
\begin{array}{rccl}
&\|Du-Dv\|^2 & =&\|Du\|^2 + 2 \langle Du, Dv \rangle + \|Dv\|^2\\
& &\ge & \|Du\|^2 -\|Dv\|^2 \\
\end{array}
$$
Equivalentemente,
$$
\|Dv\|^2  \ge  \langle Du, Dv \rangle\\
$$

Comment: Thanks again. However, whenever $\|u-v\|_{H}$ can become small, on the other hand, $\|u\|_{H^1}+\|u\|_{H^1}$ or not? I thought this too.

Comment: Not sure what your point is? The norms are finite and when e.g. $v$ converges to $u$ (in $H^1$) then $F(v)$ converges to $F(u)$.